# how to delete data from popup

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

i want to delete data from my view but iam not able to delete with this code
this is my jquery code...

```
$(".deleteimage").click(function (e) {
    var url = $(this).parent().attr('href');
    $("#dialog-delete").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height: 180,
        width: 300,
        show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up" },
        modal: true,
        draggable: false,
        open: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).load(url);
        }, 
        buttons: {
            "OK": function () {
                $(this).remove;

            }, "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            } 
        },
         close: function (event, ui) {
                      $(this).dialog('close');
                 }

    });
    $("#dialog-delete").dialog('open');

    return false;
});
```

this is my delete action method

```
 @(new HtmlString(@Ajax.ImageActionLink("../../Content/images/grid/Del.png", "Delete", "Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.TerminalID }, "deleteimage", new AjaxOptions
         {
             HttpMethod = "GET",
             InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
             UpdateTargetId = "targetdiv"
       }))) 

    <div id="dialog-edit"></div>
      <div id="dialog-delete" style="display:none"></div>
```

can someone suggest me any wrong in that....

Answer (score 0):

what exactly are you trying to remove here?
i don't know exactly what the remove method is supposed to do, but i generally do in this scenarios is ".html("");" provided you give a container this clears any html in it.

Comment: i want to know which function to use for deleting data instead of this:........ function () {$(this).remove;

Comment: this function i gave you ".html()" can be used to remove html content from a container. Is this not what you want?